# Error when creating a custom view

Tags: android, view

I'm very new to android. I've been reading a whole lot of tutorials. But I want to get a simple piece of code to work. I want to do a card game. So I thought I'd start with creating a class that draws a rounded rectangle of a specific dimiension (I don't want to sell or share the game so portability is not an issue).

This is the class I wrote:

```
public class Card extends View{

RectF borders;  
Paint paint;
float rad;

public Card(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    borders.set((float)0.0, (float)0.0, (float)2.5, (float)3.5);
    rad = 1;
    paint.setARGB(0, 117, 217, 222);        
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){       
    canvas.drawRoundRect(borders, rad, rad, paint);
}

}
```

I created a Linear layout in xml and then this is code for the main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

LinearLayout HandLayout;
Card card;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    HandLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.hand_gallery);
    HandLayout.addView(card);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

When I execute that I get an NullPointer Exception. My guess is because I should add a line like card = new Card(context) but I don't know where to get the context...

Thanks for any help!!!

EDIT:

This is the error code

```
12-14 14:23:36.900: E/AndroidRuntime(22580): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-14 14:23:36.900: E/AndroidRuntime(22580): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{legen.dary/legen.dary.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-14 14:23:36.900: E/AndroidRuntime(22580):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
12-14 14:23:36.900: E/AndroidRuntime(22580):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
12-14 14:23:36.900: E/AndroidRuntime(22580):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
12-14 14:23:36.900: E/AndroidRuntime(22580):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
12-14 14:23:36.900: E/AndroidRuntime(22580):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-14 14:23:36.900: E/AndroidRuntime(22580):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-14 14:23:36.900: E/AndroidRuntime(22580):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
12-14 14:23:36.900: E/AndroidRuntime(22580):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-14 14:23:36.900: E/AndroidRuntime(22580):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-14 14:23:36.900: E/AndroidRuntime(22580):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
12-14 14:23:36.900: E/AndroidRuntime(22580):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-14 14:23:36.900: E/AndroidRuntime(22580):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-14 14:23:36.900: E/AndroidRuntime(22580): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-14 14:23:36.900: E/AndroidRuntime(22580):    at legen.dary.Card.<init>(Card.java:18)
12-14 14:23:36.900: E/AndroidRuntime(22580):    at legen.dary.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
12-14 14:23:36.900: E/AndroidRuntime(22580):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
12-14 14:23:36.900: E/AndroidRuntime(22580):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
12-14 14:23:36.900: E/AndroidRuntime(22580):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
12-14 14:23:36.900: E/AndroidRuntime(22580):    ... 11 more
```

I have tried the following changes to code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

LinearLayout HandLayout;
Card card;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    HandLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.hand_gallery);
    card = new Card(this);
    HandLayout.addView(card);

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RectF borders;  
Paint paint;
float rad;

public Card(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    borders.set((float)0.0, (float)0.0, (float)2.5, (float)3.5);
    rad = 1;
    paint.setARGB(0, 117, 217, 222);        
}
```

Your `borders` and `paint` are not initialized here. That's what causes the NPE.

To get something displayed, also consider the following:

- Your alpha value is 0 i.e. completely transparent. Consider using 255 instead.
- The `borders` coordinates are close to 0 so whatever gets drawn is quite small. Consider increasing the `2.5` and `3.5` to something bigger.

Comment: Thank you!! That was it. I doesn't crash anymore!!!! I can't believe I've forgot about initialization in such a simple code.....

Comment: @user792589 Updated answer with a couple of bullets to get your card to render.

Comment: Thank you!! However I followed your recomendations and no luck. There is still no rectangle being shown.... Any more ideas....

Comment: I've made it work, by adding  layout programatically as well. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

write your onCreate() like this-

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    HandLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.hand_gallery);
    HandLayout.addView(new Card(this));

}
```

Comment: you have not initialized the borders object in Card class

Comment: Yes! thank you. Another kind soul already pointed that out. I've solved it and I got no more crashes. Howevever no rectangle is drawn in the screen......

Answer (score 0):

use `new Card(this)` because [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) extends Context